# Chrome Web Server won't shut down

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've installed the Chrome Extension "Chrome Web Server". I pointed it to a local folder C:\works. That worked, I was able to run the website. Unfortunately, when I run any other Node application locally, Chrome now always displays the site at C:\works at localhost:3000. I've even deleted the extension, but still am unable to run any other local web app - localhost:3000 always just still points to the site configured in Chrome Web Server- that I deleted!

I am able to view the other Node apps in other browsers at localhost:3000, but not Chrome.

Comment: Try asking on that extension's site/forum. Maybe it sets a persistent *workspace* mapping which you will see in devtools settings.

Comment: Just change the port of your other web servers to something that isn't 3000 for now